# Weird behavior of SSH, not using proper key comment

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

- Whenever, I `ssh-copy-id` for the first time it puts my `username@host` at the end of the authorized_keys file line as expected.

On Remote machine:

```
sacredos@sacredos-DT:~$ cat /home/sacredos/.ssh/auth*
ssh-rsa ... sacredos@sacredos-LT
```

On Local machine:

```
sacredos@sacredos-LT:~$ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:... sacredos@sacredos-LT (RSA)
```

- When, I go to `ssh-copy-id` to another computer or subsequent ones, it puts the path to the id file there instead.

On Remote machine after clearing and recopying the key over:

```
sacredos@sacredos-DT:~$ cat /home/sacredos/.ssh/auth*
ssh-rsa ... /home/sacredos/.ssh/id_rsa
```

On Local machine after copying the key over again:

```
sacredos@sacredos-LT:~$ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:... /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

- I installed a system fresh to check that is not something I did with configs and such but it behaves the same. It also doesn't matter if it is the same machine in a cleared state or a new machine, if the key is ssh-copy-id'ed over two times or more this happens.

What is going on here?

Comment: This is really unclear. Can you give more explicit and reproducible examples of what you expected to see and what you actually saw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `ssh-copy-id(1)` man page:

> Default behaviour without `-i`, is to check if `ssh-add -L` provides any
>        output, and if so those keys are used.  Note that this results in the
>        **comment on the key being the filename that was given to `ssh-add(1)`** when
>        the key was loaded into your `ssh-agent(1)` rather than the comment contained in that file, which is a bit of a shame.  Otherwise, if `ssh-add(1)`
>        provides no keys contents of the `default_ID_file` will be used.

So you should always use eg. `-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (as mentioned in the manpage) or dispense with using `ssh-agent` if you want to preserve the comment from the identity file.

Notice that by default on debian (and probably on ubuntu too) a GUI session is run as a subprocess of `ssh-agent` (look at `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent`), so you will be using `ssh-agent` even if you didn't mean to.

Also, the key will be automatically added to `ssh-agent` when running `ssh` (via `ssh-copy-id`), without having to run `ssh-add`, if you have the `AddKeysToAgent` option enabled (see the `ssh_config(5)` manpage).